# List products for specific category

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3, cs-cart

I am trying to list 4 products based on the category of the product I am in, so if I were viewing "Cool product" which has the category "Awesome category", I would like to view 4 of the latest "Awesome category" products within that product.

I know that this can be achieved by manually adding products for each product to a specific block, unfortunately there are way too many products for this approach to be feasible.

I have gotten to the point where I am able to get the id's of the latest 4 products based on the current products category, but I am unable to get the thumb image or the product's URL, here is what I have thus far,

```
{php}
    $pid = $this->get_template_vars("product");
    $pid = $pid["product_id"];

    $cid = db_get_field("SELECT category_id FROM cscart_products_categories WHERE product_id = '$pid' AND link_type = 'M';");
    $prod_ids = db_get_fields("SELECT * FROM cscart_products_categories WHERE category_id = '$cid' LIMIT 4;");

    foreach($prod_ids as $prod_id){
        echo $prod_id;
    }

    print_r($prods);

{/php}
```

as you can see I have PHP enabled in the config. So in conclusion, I would like to display 4 products, inside of the product I am currently viewing, based on the current products category.

Comment: How does cscart_products_categories table look like?

Comment: Why are mixing your logic with your presentation? Isn't smarty about stopping that?

Comment: @Marcus The table structure for cscart_products_categories looks like this, `product_id(mediumint), category_id(mediumint), link_type(char), position(smallint)`. @Sammaye I am not as familliar with Smarty, so I am unsure of the best way to proceed. I do know that it would be best to use an add-on to achieve the desired result, but unfortunately I am pressed for time.

Comment: Ok, great. A few more questions.

What is the $prods variable, I can´t see it defined anywhere.

Do you actually get the IDs printed in your foreach loop?

Since you are selecting *, shouldn´t you get all columns so that this line prod_ids = db_get_fields("SELECT * FROM cscart_products_categories WHERE category_id = '$cid' LIMIT 4;"); actually returns the full result set and can´t you access your columns like this, $prod_ids['category_id'], $prod_ids['link_type'] etc.?

Where do you have the thumnail image/url and the products url stored? Columnds in db?

Answer (score 0):

**way 1** - when you have category_id

```
http://x.com/index.php?dispatch=categories.view&category_id=45
```

**way 2** - when you have a product_id or a category_id

do a query (ex. for category)

```
select * from cscart_seo_redirects where object_id = 45 and type = 'c' and lang_code='en'
```

then read the **src** field!